# Image Watermark Error: Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path =''

Tags: flutter, image, firebase-storage

I am new to Flutter and coding. I followed the guide [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/add-watermark-over-image-in-flutter-e7353e3cf603) for how to add a watermark to an image. However, I am not using image picker, but using an image stored within Firebase, and a watermark that is an asset.

The code builds fine, but when I press the button to generate the watermarked image and eventually share it, I get the following error

> Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'firebase url path' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

It is recognizing the path to the image in Firebase, but for some reason is saying the file isn't available. The error is being thrown on the 'decodeImage' portion of the code below.

Code snippet below

```
import '../backend/image_share/image_share.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as ui;
import 'dart:io';

onPressed: () async {
    //first image is a firebase path
    final pickedFile = File('firebae path');
    //second image is watermark and an asset
    final watermark = File('assets/images/Share-small.png');
    ui.Image originalImage = ui.decodeImage(pickedFile.readAsBytesSync());
    ui.Image watermarkImage = ui.decodeImage(watermark.readAsBytesSync());
    ui.drawImage(originalImage, watermarkImage);
    ui.drawString(originalImage, ui.arial_24, 100, 120, 'Test!');
    List<int> wmImage = ui.encodePng(originalImage);
    final uploadUrl = await uploadData('new firebase data', wmImage);
    
    final 'new firebase data' = FB collection(sharedImage: uploadUrl);
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to read/upload the image file before manipulating them.

Answer (score 1):

The `File` class can only read/write files that are on the local system. It does not have any knowledge of files in Cloud Storage.

You will need to:

1. [download the file](https://www.google.com/search?q=flutter+download+file+from+url) from Cloud Storage,
2. add the watermark on the device, and then
3. [write the resulting file](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage#uploading-files) back to Cloud Storage.

Comment: Thanks @Frank van Puffelen for the reply. Reading through the ways to download the file first there are a lot of options and packages. Is there a preferred method of doing downloading from a url and a preferred temporary storage method?

Comment: Recommending a specific way is off topic, but I'd typically either start from the top search result, from a high-voted package on pub.dev, or this also looks promising: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data.